# Samsung front camera issue

Tags: android, camera, rotation, samsung-mobile

I'm using 
`Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` 
to get a photo from the camera, it works fine on all devices, except for samsung devices where if you take photo with the frontal camera it appears rotated 180 degrees.

I can rotate the image 180 degrees to correct the issue with the frontal camera, but this causes the rear camera photos to be rotated as well.

Is there any way I can detect which camera is taking the picture, and therefore only rotate the frontal camera's images?

Comment: Are you examining the EXIF orientation tag, and rotating based on it?

Comment: Yes, but orientation tag is always 0 .

Comment: `can rotate the image 180 degrees`. How do you get the image? Or bitmap? Bitmaps have no exif info. Unclear what you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works fine on all devices

No offense, but I rather doubt that. There are a *lot* of buggy camera apps. Bear in mind that some of those buggy camera apps are user-installed, not just pre-installed.

> Is there any way I can detect which camera is taking the picture

Not really. I do not see [an EXIF tag](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) for that, and there is no requirement that the camera app put the tag in the image anyway. You are not told any details about the picture other than the picture itself. You could try playing some games, looking at the image resolution and comparing it with possible camera resolutions, but that will be unreliable.

In general, with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you just wind up living with spotty results. Your primary alternative is to use a library to embed photo capture into your app (e.g., CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat), trading off the unreliability of third-party camera apps with the unreliability of device manufacturer camera API support.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with the second option!